# Порядок изучения веб технологий

Tags: html, html5, javascript, css

Статьи по html-js-css быстро устаревают, ввиду быстрого развития веб технологий. И чтобы нормально верстать требуется изучать много раз одно и то же, поверх старого. Когда я начал изучать html по урокам на каком то сайте, большинство тегов форматирования применялось к html, а не к css. Что в итоге приводило к избыточности и разметочной каше. Потом я стал изучать эти технологии при помощи codeacademy. Хоть он более современен, странички которые делаются в их уроках кошмарны? Поделитесь советом, какие книги читать, какие книги использовать, на каких сайтах грамотная документация.

Fix: Задавал этот вопрос одному человеку который делает хорошие уроки по веб технологиям, но потом решил что тут мне быстрее и лучше ответят. Забыл поправить вопрос.

Comment: > Единственные адекватные уроки ваши. Но в ваших уроках я много чего не понимаю.
Шито?

Comment: В наше время есть **материк информаций - Google**.

Comment: Это ТС наверное про ХэшКод. 
По теме:
"Статьи по html-js-css быстро устаревают" - не настолько быстро, чтобы не успевать выучить основы за адекватный период времени.
"какие книги читать" - иностранных авторов, изданных хорошим, годным издательством, например, O'reilly

Answer (score 8):

Универсальные способ — начать делать реальный проект, пускай даже для себя.
Возникает затруднение — читаем мануалы, желательно обращая внимания на даты и технологии.
Если это простая верстка — HTML5, использование фрейворков, таких как Twitter Bootstrap. Это позволит хотя бы на время абстрагироваться от проблем совместимости.

С JavaScript аналогично — jQuery, наборы компонентов, но не боятся иногда изобретать велосипед для развития и изучать с запасом от потребностей. Не боятся проходить одно и то же несколько раз, но опять же — без практики и реальных задач (или огромной фантазии) можно застрять навечно в изучении ньюансов и особенностей в чем угодно.

Answer (score 7):

**Боже избавь вас изучать веб-технологии по фреймфоркам!!!**
Никаких жквери и иже снмими, пока не появится понимание чистого хтмл/цсс (http://htmlbook.ru), чистого джаваскрипт (http://learn.javascript.ru) и работы серверной стороны (http://www.php.su).
Ну и да, желательно взять какой-то проект для реализации. Браузерный сокобан, арканоид, пэкмэн и т.д...

Comment: Иже еси на небеси, избави нас от PHP

Comment: @pirj чем пэхапэ не угодил? Меня вроде как не травмировало. А плохие прогеры сами отсеяться в более низшие круги.

Comment: Можно и без Всевышнего -- просто не подходить к php близко. А насчёт языков вспомнилось (автор, кажется, Антон Москаль). "Чайник с C++ куда опасней, чем чайник с Visual Basic"

Comment: @devian Начинать надо с rfc2616 -- "Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1"

Answer (score 5):

Авторитетный ресурс - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/). За остальное в сети ручаться не буду. Однако, он не школа и не курс молодого бойца. Вам всё равно понадобится какой-то язык для серверной стороны. Выбирайте, что для вас ближе и проще - Node.js,  Python, Ruby, Scala (в алфавитном порядке, порядок предпочтения у каждого свой), и изучайте, все они работают с веб. Не берите PHP, он склоняет новичков к плохому стилю программирования. Не берите Java, он излишне сложен для новичков. Приготовьтесь к тому, что разработка более проста на Linux/OSX, нежели под Windows. Поставьте виртуальную машину, проще всего это делать с Vagrant/VirtualBox. Начините писать блог или сайт рецептов. Используйте бесплатный апп-хостинг типа AppEngine или Heroku. Всё потихоньку придёт.

Comment: плюсонул, но все же с тем, что Java слишком сложен для новичков, не согласен. Как раз с языков вроде Java и стоит изучать программирование...Хотя, если человек не видел ничего, кроме HTML/CSS, то да, Java будет сложноват

Comment: @DreamChild Java синтаксис для веб-приложений перегружен лишним. А если уж браться сразу за Play, то можно делать это со Scala, а лучше сразу с Ruby on Rails, с которого первый слизан.

Comment: >Java синтаксис для веб-приложений перегружен лишним

например чем?

Comment: Java:

    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class Hello extends HttpServlet {

      public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("Hello World!");
        out.println("</body></html>");
      }
    }

Ruby:

    require 'sinatra'

    get '/' do
      """<html><body>
      Hello World!
      </body></html>
      """
    end

Comment: а еще оно дико пугает своими ошибками, в которых новичку тяжело разобраться :)

Comment: @thunder: ну, у любой платформы пугающие ошибки есть, в которых новичку тяжело разобраться
Просто если это Django или Ruby on Rails, то в сети куча примеров (хотя часто и устаревших), документации итп, что трудно сказать про Play.

Comment: @pirj Не хочу показаться троллем, но чем второй вариант лучше первого?